# Web app in tomcat 9.0.14 crash and I can't see anything in catalina.out but I have other applications working in other instances

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat9

I have 3 web apps in a tomcat 9.0.14 using java 8 and primefaces 3.2 running in different instances ports (8080, 9080, 10080) but more o less each 6 days the web app installed in the port 10080 crash and can't be accesed for the users (I have and tomcat manager too and I can't acces to it, all the instance doesn´t work), but I can't see any error in the log, the web app just stop working and writting in the catalina.out (the other web apps are working fine ) until I restart the tomcat I get this stacktrace

```
2019-11-06 08:30:53 | 28846 | 1 | HorarioEjecucionProcesosNocturnosJobs | eliminarTodosJob  >> Dentro de la funcion eliminarTodosJob
2019-11-06 08:30:53 | 28846 | 1 | HorarioEjecucionProcesosNocturnosJobs | eliminarTodosJob  >> Eliminando JOB: Actualizacion de referencias hipotecas
2019-11-06 08:30:53 | 28846 | 1 | HorarioEjecucionProcesosNocturnosJobs | eliminarTodosJob  >> Eliminando JOB: Cambio de planes
2019-11-06 08:30:53 | 28846 | 1 | HorarioEjecucionProcesosNocturnosJobs | eliminarTodosJob  >> Eliminando JOB: Renovaciones de certificados
2019-11-06 08:30:53 | 28846 | 1 | HorarioEjecucionProcesosNocturnosJobs | eliminarTodosJob  >> Eliminando JOB: Actualizacion de cuotas de hipotecas
2019-11-06 08:30:53 | 28846 | 1 | HorarioEjecucionProcesosNocturnosJobs | eliminarTodosJob  >> Eliminando JOB: Preparación de cobros
2019-11-06 08:30:53 | 28846 | 1 | HorarioEjecucionProcesosNocturnosJobs | eliminarTodosJob  >> Eliminando JOB: Disparador de cobros de cuentas y TdC
2019-11-06 08:30:53 | 28846 | 1 | HorarioEjecucionProcesosNocturnosJobs | eliminarTodosJob  >> Eliminando JOB: Cargos a tarjeta de crédito
2019-11-06 08:30:53 | 28846 | 1 | HorarioEjecucionProcesosNocturnosJobs | eliminarTodosJob  >> Eliminando JOB: Cálculo de mora
2019-11-06 08:30:53 | 28846 | 1 | HorarioEjecucionProcesosNocturnosJobs | eliminarTodosJob  >> Eliminando JOB: Envio notificaciones seguro ATM         
2019-11-06 08:30:53 | 28846 | 1 | HorarioEjecucionProcesosNocturnosJobs | eliminarTodosJob  >> Eliminando JOB: Cargos recurrentes en cuentas
2019-11-06 08:30:53 | 28846 | 1 | HorarioEjecucionProcesosNocturnosJobs | obtenerListaJob  >> en la funcion obtenerListaJob 
2019-11-06 08:30:53 | 28846 | 1 | HorarioEjecucionProcesosNocturnosJobs | detenerJobs  >> el la funcion detener jobs
2019-11-06 08:30 53 Criticidad :  INFO, Clase : org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler, Metodo : shutdown , mensaje : Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down. , linea : 542 
 2019-11-06 08:30 53 Criticidad :  INFO, Clase : org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler, Metodo : standby , mensaje : Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused. , linea : 470 
 2019-11-06 08:30 53 Criticidad :  INFO, Clase : org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler, Metodo : shutdown , mensaje : Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete. , linea : 592 
 06-Nov-2019 08:30:53.667 SEVERE [main] com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:804)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:306)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:108)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:327)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4710)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5353)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1387)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:974)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1387)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:974)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal(StandardService.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stopInternal(StandardServer.java:995)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:672)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)

06-Nov-2019 08:30:53.687 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [BancaSegurosVida] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:590)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:424)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:345)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.utilidades.Jndi.getJndiConnection(Jndi.java:23)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.daoImp.EnvioNotificacionesSATMDaoImpl.validarDatos(EnvioNotificacionesSATMDaoImpl.java:109)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.daoImp.ProcesoNocturnoDaoImp.ejecutarProcesoEnvioNotificaciones(ProcesoNocturnoDaoImp.java:674)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.procesosNocturnos.ProcesoNocturnoEnvioNotificacionesSATM.execute(ProcesoNocturnoEnvioNotificacionesSATM.java:20)
 org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
06-Nov-2019 08:30:53.690 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [BancaSegurosVida] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:590)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:424)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:345)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.utilidades.Jndi.getJndiConnection(Jndi.java:23)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.daoImp.EnvioNotificacionesSATMDaoImpl.validarDatos(EnvioNotificacionesSATMDaoImpl.java:109)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.daoImp.ProcesoNocturnoDaoImp.ejecutarProcesoEnvioNotificaciones(ProcesoNocturnoDaoImp.java:674)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.procesosNocturnos.ProcesoNocturnoEnvioNotificacionesSATM.execute(ProcesoNocturnoEnvioNotificacionesSATM.java:20)
 org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
06-Nov-2019 08:30:53.692 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [BancaSegurosVida] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:590)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:424)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:345)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.utilidades.Jndi.getJndiConnection(Jndi.java:23)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.daoImp.EnvioNotificacionesSATMDaoImpl.validarDatos(EnvioNotificacionesSATMDaoImpl.java:109)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.daoImp.ProcesoNocturnoDaoImp.ejecutarProcesoEnvioNotificaciones(ProcesoNocturnoDaoImp.java:674)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.procesosNocturnos.ProcesoNocturnoEnvioNotificacionesSATM.execute(ProcesoNocturnoEnvioNotificacionesSATM.java:20)
 org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
06-Nov-2019 08:30:53.695 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [BancaSegurosVida] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:590)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:424)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:345)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.utilidades.Jndi.getJndiConnection(Jndi.java:23)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.daoImp.EnvioNotificacionesSATMDaoImpl.validarDatos(EnvioNotificacionesSATMDaoImpl.java:109)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.daoImp.ProcesoNocturnoDaoImp.ejecutarProcesoEnvioNotificaciones(ProcesoNocturnoDaoImp.java:674)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.procesosNocturnos.ProcesoNocturnoEnvioNotificacionesSATM.execute(ProcesoNocturnoEnvioNotificacionesSATM.java:20)
 org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
06-Nov-2019 08:30:53.697 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [BancaSegurosVida] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:590)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:424)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:345)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.utilidades.Jndi.getJndiConnection(Jndi.java:23)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.daoImp.EnvioNotificacionesSATMDaoImpl.validarDatos(EnvioNotificacionesSATMDaoImpl.java:109)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.daoImp.ProcesoNocturnoDaoImp.ejecutarProcesoEnvioNotificaciones(ProcesoNocturnoDaoImp.java:674)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.procesosNocturnos.ProcesoNocturnoEnvioNotificacionesSATM.execute(ProcesoNocturnoEnvioNotificacionesSATM.java:20)
 org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
06-Nov-2019 08:30:53.700 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [BancaSegurosVida] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:590)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:424)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:345)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.utilidades.Jndi.getJndiConnection(Jndi.java:23)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.daoImp.EnvioNotificacionesSATMDaoImpl.validarDatos(EnvioNotificacionesSATMDaoImpl.java:109)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.daoImp.ProcesoNocturnoDaoImp.ejecutarProcesoEnvioNotificaciones(ProcesoNocturnoDaoImp.java:674)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.procesosNocturnos.ProcesoNocturnoEnvioNotificacionesSATM.execute(ProcesoNocturnoEnvioNotificacionesSATM.java:20)
 org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
06-Nov-2019 08:30:53.702 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [BancaSegurosVida] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:590)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:424)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:345)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.utilidades.Jndi.getJndiConnection(Jndi.java:23)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.daoImp.EnvioNotificacionesSATMDaoImpl.validarDatos(EnvioNotificacionesSATMDaoImpl.java:109)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.daoImp.ProcesoNocturnoDaoImp.ejecutarProcesoEnvioNotificaciones(ProcesoNocturnoDaoImp.java:674)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.procesosNocturnos.ProcesoNocturnoEnvioNotificacionesSATM.execute(ProcesoNocturnoEnvioNotificacionesSATM.java:20)
 org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
06-Nov-2019 08:30:53.705 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [BancaSegurosVida] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:590)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:424)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:345)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.utilidades.Jndi.getJndiConnection(Jndi.java:23)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.daoImp.EnvioNotificacionesSATMDaoImpl.validarDatos(EnvioNotificacionesSATMDaoImpl.java:109)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.daoImp.ProcesoNocturnoDaoImp.ejecutarProcesoEnvioNotificaciones(ProcesoNocturnoDaoImp.java:674)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.procesosNocturnos.ProcesoNocturnoEnvioNotificacionesSATM.execute(ProcesoNocturnoEnvioNotificacionesSATM.java:20)
 org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
06-Nov-2019 08:30:53.707 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [BancaSegurosVida] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:590)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:424)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:345)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.utilidades.Jndi.getJndiConnection(Jndi.java:23)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.daoImp.EnvioNotificacionesSATMDaoImpl.validarDatos(EnvioNotificacionesSATMDaoImpl.java:109)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.daoImp.ProcesoNocturnoDaoImp.ejecutarProcesoEnvioNotificaciones(ProcesoNocturnoDaoImp.java:674)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.procesosNocturnos.ProcesoNocturnoEnvioNotificacionesSATM.execute(ProcesoNocturnoEnvioNotificacionesSATM.java:20)
 org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
06-Nov-2019 08:30:53.710 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [BancaSegurosVida] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:590)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:424)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:345)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.utilidades.Jndi.getJndiConnection(Jndi.java:23)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.daoImp.EnvioNotificacionesSATMDaoImpl.validarDatos(EnvioNotificacionesSATMDaoImpl.java:109)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.daoImp.ProcesoNocturnoDaoImp.ejecutarProcesoEnvioNotificaciones(ProcesoNocturnoDaoImp.java:674)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.procesosNocturnos.ProcesoNocturnoEnvioNotificacionesSATM.execute(ProcesoNocturnoEnvioNotificacionesSATM.java:20)
 org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:529)
06-Nov-2019 08:30:53.712 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [BancaSegurosVida] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation. Stack trace of request processing thread:[
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:590)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:424)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:345)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
 org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.utilidades.Jndi.getJndiConnection(Jndi.java:23)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.utilidades.GeneradorReportesUtil.asignarListaParametrosReporte(GeneradorReportesUtil.java:55)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.beans.AperturaCertificado.crearPdf(AperturaCertificado.java:2219)
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1199.invoke(Unknown Source)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
 org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
 javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)
 javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
 javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:777)
 javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
 javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
 javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:928)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
 com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 com.seguros.segurosVida.utilidades.log.ErrorJsfHandling.doFilter(ErrorJsfHandling.java:31)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:53)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)]
```

Comment: Why do you think this is PrimeFaces related? I personally suspect thread or database starvation. PrimeFaces only occurs in one thread and it might just be active. Create threaddumps at different intervals and see which ones are stuck

Comment: I don't think is PrimeFaces related, it was only to give context about my issue, I was suspecting it is a thread problem but in production environment it happens close to once a week and I don't know how to replicate in development env

Comment: Tags are not for context, they are for what is actively playing a big part on the problem. Other context (in which version info is very relevant) should be given in the question. Did you google for _" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
"_ ?